# R connect Mysql using ssh

Tags: mysql, r

Hi im try connect to database using ssh
im creare new .R file using Rsudio and
run next code

```
library(RMySQL)
drv <- dbDriver("MySQL") 
mydb<- dbConnect(drv, user='myuser', password='mypass', dbname='nydb', host='myip' )
```

but its return error:

> Error in .local(drv, ...) :    Failed to connect to database: Error:
>   Can't connect to MySQL server on 'myip' (0)

Comment: From the docs it looks like the argument should be `username` not `user` which may be causing an issue otherwise we need more information.

Comment: im editting
mydb<- dbConnect(drv, username='myuser', password='mypass', dbname='nydb', host='myip' )
But error dont remove

Comment: developers give me  ssh password and ssh username, where i can entred it?

Comment: I think the host should be the server hostname and not your IP address.

Comment: Does the procedure [described here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/access-your-mysql-server-remotely-over-ssh/) work for you (and setting `host='localhost'` in `mydb`)?

Comment: iwhy localhost?
im connect to external database